# Watch dog for blocking function call

Tags: c#, multithreading, watchdog

I have a closed-source API for some hardware sensor that I use to query that sensor. The API comes as DLL that I use through C# interop. The API's functions are blocking. They usually return error values but in some cases they just won't return.

I need to be able to detect this situation and in that case kill the blocked thread. How can this be done in C#?

The thread they're being invoked on is created through a BackgroundWorker. I'm looking for a simple watch dog for blocking function calls that I can set up before calling the function and reset when I'm back. It should just sit there and wait for me to come back. If I don't, it shall kill the thread so that 1) the API is freed up again and no thread of my application is still hanging around and doing *anything* should it eventually return and 2) I can take other recovery measures like re-initialising the API to continue working with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to set up a System.Threading.Timer before the API call to fire after a certain timeout interval, then dispose the Timer after the call completes.  If the Timer fires, it'll fire on a ThreadPool thread, and you can then take appropriate action to kill the offending thread.

Note that you'll need to P/Invoke to the Win32 TerminateThread API, since .NET's Thread.Abort() won't work if you're blocked in unmanaged code.

Also note that it's **very** unlikely your process will be in a safe state after forcibly killing a thread, as the terminated thread might be holding synchronization objects, might have been in the middle of mutating shared memory state, or any other such critical operation.  As a result of terminating it, other threads may hang, the process may crash, data may be corrupted, dogs and cats might start living together; there's no way of being sure what'll happen, but chances are it'll be bad.  The safest approach, if possible, would be to isolate usage of the API into a separate process that you communicate with via some remoting channel. Then you can kill that external process on demand, as killing a process is a lot safer than killing a thread.

Comment: Good answer. Besides cats and dogs living together, memory will leak when you kill threads. I like your suggestion of having a separate process that can be killed. Cleanup that way is more automatic.

Comment: +1: Agreed. Separate process is the best way to go. It sucks, but so is life sometimes.

Comment: The separate process idea is good indeed. It would also save me from building the whole managed application for x86 because I only have a 32 bit version of that unmanaged DLL. (Just looking whether other ideas come up still.)